# How to set first <li> link as active in a php menu

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi I am working with a Wordpress gallery plugin.

I would like the first link in the filter menu to automatically be active when the page loads. This is as by default it loads ALL the images from all the categories and it's too many! Thanks.

```
 <?php


wp_enqueue_script('imagesloaded', plugins_url('/assets/plugins/imagesloaded/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), GO_GALLERY_VERSION, true);
wp_enqueue_script('isotope', plugins_url('/assets/plugins/isotope/isotope.pkgd.min.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), GO_GALLERY_VERSION, true);

wp_enqueue_script('go-gallery', plugins_url('/assets/js/gallery.js', __FILE__), array('jquery', 'isotope', 'imagesloaded'), GO_GALLERY_VERSION, true);
wp_enqueue_style('go-gallery', plugins_url('/assets/css/gallery.css', __FILE__), null, GO_GALLERY_VERSION);

wp_enqueue_script('tos', plugins_url('/assets/plugins/tos/js/jquery.tosrus.min.custom.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), GO_GALLERY_VERSION, true);
wp_enqueue_style('tos', plugins_url('/assets/plugins/tos/css/jquery.tosrus.custom.css', __FILE__), null, GO_GALLERY_VERSION);



$labels = array(
    'name'              => _x('Media Categories', 'taxonomy general name', 'go_gallery'),
    'singular_name'     => _x('Media Category', 'taxonomy singular name', 'go_gallery'),
    'search_items'      => __('Search Media Categories', 'go_gallery'),
    'all_items'         => __('All Media Categories', 'go_gallery'),
    'parent_item'       => __('Parent Media Category', 'go_gallery'),
    'parent_item_colon' => __('Parent Media Category:', 'go_gallery'),
    'edit_item'         => __('Edit Media Category', 'go_gallery'),
    'update_item'       => __('Update Media Category', 'go_gallery'),
    'add_new_item'      => __('Add New Media Category', 'go_gallery'),
    'new_item_name'     => __('New Media Category Name', 'go_gallery'),
    'menu_name'         => __('Media Categories', 'go_gallery'),
);

$args = array(
    'hierarchical'      => TRUE,
    'labels'            => $labels,
    'show_ui'           => TRUE,
    'show_admin_column' => TRUE,
    'query_var'         => TRUE,
    'rewrite'           => TRUE,
);

register_taxonomy('attachment_category', 'attachment',  $args );



$output = '';

$args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'attachment',
    'post_status'       => 'inherit',
    'posts_per_page'    => $atts['limit'],
    'order'             => 'DESC',
    'orderby'           => $atts['sort'],
    'post_mime_type'    => 'image/jpeg,image/gif,image/jpg,image/png'
);


$categories = array();

$atts['icat'] = array_map('sanitize_title', explode(',', $atts['icat']));

foreach ( $atts['icat'] as $category ) {

    if ( $term = get_term_by('slug', $category, 'attachment_category') ) {
        $categories[$term->term_id] = $term;
    }

}

if ( !empty($categories) ) {
    $args['tax_query'] = array(
        array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'attachment_category',
            'field'     => 'term_id',
            'terms'     => array_keys($categories)
        )
    );
}

$atts['menu_gap'] = min($atts['menu_gap'], 100);

$classes[] = 'go-gallery';
$classes[] = 'menu-' . $atts['menu_pos'];
$classes[] = go_gallery_bool($atts['menu_show']) ? 'menu-show' : '';
$classes[] = 'size-' . $atts['size'];
$classes[] = 'style-' . $atts['style'];

$attributes = array();
$attributes['class'] = join(' ', $classes);
$attributes['id'] = 'go-' . substr(md5(mt_rand(0, PHP_INT_MAX)), 0, 6);
$attributes['data-gap'] = intval($atts['gap']);
$attributes['data-border-color'] = $atts['border_color'];
$attributes['data-lightbox'] = go_gallery_bool($atts['lightbox']) ? 'yes' : 'no';
$attributes['data-desc-color'] = $atts['desc_color'];
$attributes['data-menu-color'] = $atts['menu_color'];
$attributes['data-menu-bg'] = $atts['menu_bg'];
$attributes['data-menu-bg-hover'] = $atts['menu_bg_hover'];
$attributes['data-menu-gap'] = $atts['menu_gap'];
$attributes['data-bg'] = $atts['bg'];
$attributes['data-border-size'] = $atts['border_size'];
$attributes['data-overlay-color'] = go_gallery_hex2rgb($atts['overlay_color']);

$thumb_size = 'medium';

if ( $atts['size'] == 'large' || ($atts['style'] == 'squared' && in_array($atts['size'], array('medium', 'large'))) ) {
    $thumb_size = 'large';
}

foreach ( $attributes as $attribute => $value ) {
    $attributes[$attribute] = $attribute . '="' . $value . '"';
}

$query = new WP_Query($args);

$output .= '<div ' . join(' ', $attributes) . '>';
$output .= '<ul class="go-gallery-filters">';
$output .= '<li>';
$output .= '<a data-filter="" href="#">' . __($atts['menu_button'], 'go_gallery') . '</a>';
$output .= '</li>';

foreach ( $categories as $category ) {

    if ( !empty($category) ) {

        $output .= '<li class="active">';
        $output .= '<a data-filter="' . $category->slug . '" href="#">' . $category->name . '</a>';
        $output .= '</li>';
    }

}

$output .= '</ul>';

$output .= '<div class="go-gallery-list-wrapper">';
$output .= '<ul class="go-gallery-list">';

foreach ( $query->posts as $post ) {

    $category_terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'attachment_category');

    $classes = array();
    $classes[] = 'go-gallery-item';

    foreach ( $category_terms as $category_term ) {
        $classes[] = 'category-' . $category_term->slug;
    }

    $image_source = wp_get_attachment_image_src($post->ID, 'full');

    $output .= '<li data-source="' . $image_source[0] . '" class="' . join(' ', $classes) . '">';

    $output .= '<a class="image-wrap" href="' . $image_source[0] . '">';
    $output .= '<figure>';

    $output .= wp_get_attachment_image($post->ID, $thumb_size);

    $output .= '<div class="image-overlay">';

    if ( go_gallery_bool( $atts['hover_data'] ) ){
        $output .= '<h3>' . $post->post_title . '</h3>';
        $output .= '<h4>' . $post->post_content . '</h4>';
    }

    $output .= '</div>';

    $output .= '</figure>';
    $output .= '</a>';
    $output .= '</li>';
}

$output .= '</ul>';
$output .= '</div>';
$output .= '</div>';

return $output;


if(strlen($hex) == 3) {
    $r = hexdec(substr($hex,0,1).substr($hex,0,1));
    $g = hexdec(substr($hex,1,1).substr($hex,1,1));
    $b = hexdec(substr($hex,2,1).substr($hex,2,1));
} else {
    $r = hexdec(substr($hex,0,2));
    $g = hexdec(substr($hex,2,2));
    $b = hexdec(substr($hex,4,2));
}
$rgb = array($r, $g, $b);
return 'rgba(' . join(', ', $rgb) . ', ' . $alpha .')';
```

Comment: Is there a foreach loop or anything similar containing your code?

Comment: Yes there is! foreach ( $categories as $category ) {

Comment: so you actually want to set a default value for `$category`, right?

Comment: I want the first category to be active on page load by default yes

Comment: there's not enough information to answer without quite some assumtions

Comment: sorry I updated with full code

Answer (score 1):

That depends what you mean with "active".

:active is a CSS pseudo selector that can change the appearance of a link while it is being activated. If you want to add a css-class "active" to the first li-element in your loop, you could try something like the following:

```
foreach($categories as $category) {

  $counter = 0; // COUNTER OF CATEGORIES... 
  $selected = ''; // THE STRING TO PRINT IN SELECTED LI-ELEMENT

  if ( !empty($category) ) {
    $selected = ($counter == 0) ? 'class="active"' : ''; // SET CLASS ACTIVE FOR THE FIRST CATEGORY

    $output .= '<li '. $selected .'>';
    $output .= '<a data-filter="' . $category->slug . '" href="#">' . $category->name . '</a>';
    $output .= '</li>';

    $counter++; //INCREMENT COUNTER OF CATEGORIES

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your categories get sent via a simple link like so:

```
<a href="gallery.php?category=1">first category</a>
<a href="gallery.php?category=2">second category</a>
```

then you would have something like this in php:

```
if(isset($_GET['category']) {
   $category_id = $_GET['category'];
} else {
   $category_id = 1; // default
}

// this is a blank guess, we don't know where you get your data from:
$category = $categories[$category_id];
```

The rest depends on your data-structure.
But this is how you could set a default category.